# nagios SSL handshake

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios

I have `nagios` client which gave sudden error after an upgrade. I reinstalled `nagios-plugin` and `nrpe` agent again but unable solve error. This version uses `nrpe` under `xinetd`.

```
# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H localhost
CHECK_NRPE: Error - Could not complete SSL handshake.

# netstat -plan | grep :5666
tcp        0      0 :::5666                     :::*                        LISTEN      20265/xinetd
```

`Nagios-server-IP 10.10.3.30`

```
# cat /etc/xinetd.d/nrpe | grep -i only_from
        only_from       = 127.0.0.1 10.10.3.30


# cat /etc/xinetd.d/nrpe
# default: on
# description: NRPE (Nagios Remote Plugin Executor)
service nrpe
{
        flags           = REUSE
        socket_type     = stream
        port            = 5666
        wait            = no
        user            = nagios
        group           = nagios
        server          = /usr/local/nagios/bin/nrpe
        server_args     = -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg --inetd
        log_on_failure  += USERID
        disable         = no
        only_from       = 127.0.0.1 10.10.3.30
}
```

Unable to telnet from client to server

```
# telnet 10.10.3.30 5666
Trying 10.10.3.30...
Connected to 10.10.3.30.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: no, I am trying this on client.

Comment: I have done that but still not getting the same error.

Comment: But If I am using `xinetd` instead of `nrpe` then its not necessary to add server IP in `nrpe.cfg`

Comment: Check your firewall block port 5666 or not

Comment: There is no firewall to block, but it should work on local local is also not working

Comment: What does it happens with `check_nrpe -H 10.10.3.30?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NRPE hasn't been updated in a few years ([September 2013](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nagios/files/nrpe-2.x/nrpe-2.15/)), this is what it does on the server side

```
SSL_library_init();
SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms();
meth=SSLv23_server_method();
...
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx,SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3);
...
SL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx,"ADH");
dh=get_dh512();
```

and the client (`check_nrpe` on Nagios server)

```
SSL_library_init();
SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms();
meth=SSLv23_client_method();
...
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx,SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3);
...
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx,"ADH");
```

The `SSLv23_xxx` functions used to be the most compatible way to connect to any SSLv2 or SSLv3.x system. Both of the above are [deprecated](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_new.html). While the code disables protocol versions 2.0 and 3.0 (leaving only TLS), the client connection will start with an SSLv2 ClientHello.

DH primes smaller than 1024 are [now deemed insecure](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2015/05/20/logjam-freak-upcoming-changes/) (though it might be 768 in some versions of OpenSSL).
This explains why you cannot connect to yourself, the OpenSSL client (check_nrpe) will reject a short DH key. (ADH is used since it does not need a certificate and is hence "anonymous", not a good plan in an untrusted network but acceptable for this this purpose.)

I suspect you may also be running into a second problem connecting to the new system.  What has probably happened is that the client (NSCA server) has updated to using a recent OpenSSL, SSLv2 has recently been [disabled by default](https://www.openssl.org/news/openssl-1.0.2-notes.html), though some distros have been doing that for years. In most cases there should still be an overlap in protocol/ciphersuite but it's possible and common for the TLS server (nrpe daemon in this case) with SSLv2 disabled to reject an SSLv2 *ClientHello* handshake packet, even though the client indicates SSLv3 or higher within the handshake (technical details here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/59367/what-exactly-determines-what-version-of-ssl-tls-is-used-when-accessing-a-site)

To fix this you may need to downgrade the OpenSSL on the updated system, or install a parallel older OpenSSL version which does not have these (sensible!) precautions. Neither sound like good options...

If you built `nrpe` yourself, <strike>*should* be suffient</strike> you will need to replace the call to `get_dh512()` with `get_dh1024()` *and* recompile it with a new static 1024-bit key -- to do this you will need to create a new 1024-bit prime by either modifying the hard-coded 512 in `configure` (line 6748) and rerunning it, or using

```
opensl dhparam -C 1024 | awk '/^-----/{exit} {print}' > include/dh.h
```

and then `make` to rebuild.
You will probably also need to replace the call to `SSLv23_client_method()` with `TLSv1_client_method()` also so that an SSLv2 "compatible" ClientHello is not attempted and recompile `check_nrpe` on the Nagios server. Since you run the risk of breaking connectivity to other clients then you might need a second `check_nrpe_new` binary for "upgraded" servers, and use this in  `command`/`check_command` of your templates (I don't think this should happen though).

(As a last resort you may be able to do something unpretty with `socat` or `stunnel` to bridge any mismatching, here's one way to do that: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/108850/18555 .)

A more precise answer will require the OpenSSL version (`openssl version -a`, or the relevant package manager output) and your distribution versions.

Comment: He is also doing the telnet wrong; he cannot telnet from the client to the nagios server nrpe port as only the nagios IP and localhost are accepted.

Comment: @Mr.Spuratic This the only system which is giving error, other system which is updated are not having any issues. I will try to downgrade the `openssl` version on the upgraded system and check if I overcome the error.